# UIImageView, changing .image results in relayout - can it be avoided?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a class with...

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
    showDefaultCustomProcessing()
    }
```

On one view, the user can tap and change an image...

```
@IBAction func changeDoorTap(t:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
    thing.image = UIImage(named:...new image...)
    }
```

It turns out, whenever you change `.image`, **it does a relayout of the screen**.

(I did not know that, but it makes sense.)

So unfortunately viewDidLayoutSubviews  runs and the CustomProcessing is returned to the default state. That's no good.

As a workaround I did this ........

```
var requestCustomLayoutAfterViewDidLayoutSubviews:Bool = false
@IBAction func changeDoorTap(t:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
    saveTemporaryCustomProcessing()
    thing.image = UIImage(named:...new image...)
    requestCustomLayoutAfterViewDidLayoutSubviews = true;
    }
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
    performDefaultCustomProcessing()
    if (requestCustomLayoutAfterViewDidLayoutSubviews)
        {
        recoverTemporaryCustomProcessing()
        }
    requestCustomLayoutAfterViewDidLayoutSubviews = false;
    }
```

Using such a flag is a poor pattern.

1) Is there a way to change a `.image` but **force no relayout**?

(Perhaps, by manipulating it at the layer level, or something?)

2) Can you perhaps "turn off" re-lay-out-ing and then turn it on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change a .image but force no relayout

Sure: give the UIImageView a width constraint and a height constraint. Without these, it adopts the size of its image. With them, it just obeys the constraints.

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to, but nimbly swapping constraints in and out of active state is common and encouraged and easy; I do it all the time. Apple made this very simple by providing the `activateConstraints` and `deactivateConstraints` commands.

Comment: Ah, got it !   Thanks for that

Comment: dude you may have the wrong idea, I'm a huge "tick everything" promoter!  I'm in the camp that it feels polite to wait a couple days, you know.